# How to get elasticsearch's highlight feature to truncate HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, truncation

Currently developing a search feature in a Rails app using [(re)tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) to index data.

My data includes html. The issue is that when I query my elasticsearch index and enable highlighting to highlight words that match the search term, it often returns a string that contains open html tags. Is there a way to tell elasticsearch that the data contains html?

Sample of what is being returned:

```
-at-Your-Startup">blah system, and blah is a great, to metrics at any time, and it's also the go to place to prepare for blah.  As part of the blah
```

Where `-at-Your-Startup">` is the href attribute of a link.

I know of the encode option for highlighting but it doesn't truncate html, simply escapes it. Is there a way to have elasticsearch truncate the highlight.title field?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally we index the data with HTML tags and Search in that indexed field. So this field do not contain HTML tags and hence you wont face the issue that you are currently facing.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean without HTML tags? The problem is that I've tried to index after passing it through Sanitize.fragment() or Nokogiri functions, but then the returned highlighted text will break on a url.

Comment: Yes. Without HTML Tags. But I didnt understand what issue you are facing after doing that..

Comment: If I index without HTML tags, there are still URLs in the content. So, when I try to get the highlighted field and allow it to return fragments using the lucene highlighter or postings-highlighter, it often breaks on a url. That is to the say that the beginning or end of a fragment has a leading or trailing portion of a url.